# How to create random blobs of curves in geo nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

The image below is an example I would like to reach using geometry nodes.

[image: example]

I want the blobs to have smooth boundary edges, which is why I would prefer curves. I think that using a noise texture (or similar) to distribute points and manipulating them somehow could be the way.

[image: my attempt]

I tried to feed the result of this node setup into Points to Volume node and then Volume to Mesh node, but the result was too jagged, and it's also difficult to control the height of the blobs. But it is pretty close to my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I'd start with a random surface and distribute points over it.

On those points instance some circles. Resample the circles so you get additional points for deformation later. Adjust the amount of points as desired, higher numbers will get more contorted shapes.

Realize the circle instances so they can be transformed independently. Use a *Set Position* node on the curves with the *Offset* socket connected to a *Noise* texture.

Adjust the values of the noise texture, and map them with a *Vector Math* set to *Map Range* as desired for your scene size.

[image]

The result

[image]