# Generate random curved circular shaped voids in a square

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

Can you help me to generate randomly distributed void curved circular shaped voids in a square. the figure below shows an example.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296387/how-to-create-random-blobs-of-curves-in-geo-nodes/

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I redid this model but I got shifts on the edges. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFyx2.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call this solution *experimental*, but it may help you:

[image]

The principle behind it is relatively simple, and there are a lot of possibilities to influence the result individually.

1. First I create a grid and move the single points. The node `Map Range` helps me to clamp values. With the node `Merge by Distance` I bring further disorder into the structure. Finally, I split the faces so that they can be edited separately:

   [image]
2. In the next step I move the vertices a bit into the center of each face. To do this, I convert the faces into curves, divide them once, and then select every other point to move it with a slight random value:

   [image]
3. Finally, I resample the curve to get a higher resolution and apply the node `Blur Attribute`, which smooths the positions of each curve point for me:

   [image]
4. Finally, I combine the result with a qudratic shape (`Quadrilateral`), which in this case acts as an outer frame, and `Fill Curve` creates the desired mesh:

   [image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.5+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you for this solution, if I want to convert this mesh to DXF, I add the Realize Instances node. What are the parameters to set to export this mesh in DXF.

Comment: @saded To do this, you would just have to apply the Geometry Nodes modifier, and use the DXF format when exporting.

Comment: What I know about setting these parameters: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9NC9.jpg

Comment: @saded Wouldn't it also be a possibility for you to use the FBX format? Also, it would be better if you create a new question for it, I think.

Comment: I made changes in the mesh exported to DXF, so the results are fine. Thank you very much Quellenform and Duarte Farrajota Ramos. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzR2c.png